# Can a temporary object be passed by value without destroying the original in C++

Tags: c++, vector, move

In the following code, the pointer is reset when a struct S is destructed. I'd prefer a vector of structure values instead of pointers. Is there a way to add to the vector without the temporary getting destructed?

```
int* pi = nullptr;

struct S
{
    S(int* i) { pi = i; }
    ~S() { pi = nullptr; }
};

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    int i = 5;
    std::vector<S> sVector;
    sVector.push_back(S(&i));
    std::cout << pi << std::endl; // outputs 0 instead of address
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your struct doesn't actually have any member variables - all it does is have side-effects via the constructor and destructor.

Comment: @MooseBoys: Sorry, this is just an example i made. In reality the pointer is something handled by OpenGL, and the struct is a class that calls glGenBuffers on construction and glDeleteBuffers on destruction.

Comment: It would have been less confusing if you had just added a `printf` statement inside the destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
sVector.emplace_back(&i);
```

That will construct an `S` in-place, no temporaries anywhere.

Note, however, that you have no guarantee that an append operation won't trigger a resize - and a resize would involve copying and destroying a bunch of `S`s.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you. I can reserve to avoid the resize. Is there a way to do this in the initialization? `std::vector<S> sVector = {emplace1, emplace2}`

Comment: @acerd Nope, not via the initializer list. That'd construct temporary `S`s.